# Connection pool for AWS Dynamo Db on Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This question is more on best practices when developing a web service. This may be a bit vague

Lets say my service uses Spring container which creates a standard controller object for all requests. Now, in my controller I inject an instance of Dynamo Db mapper created once in spring container. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptionalConfig.html

Question:-

Shouldn't we create a pool of DynamoDb client objects and mappers so that the parallel requests to the service are supplied from the pool? Or should we should inject same/new instance of DynamoDb mapper object for all requests? Why don't we use something like C3PO for Dynamo Db connections ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a pretty significant difference between how a relational database works and how DynamoDB works.

With a typical relational database engine such as MySQL, PostgreSQL or MSSQL, each client application instance is expected to establish a small number of connections to the engine and keep the connections open while the application is in use. Then, when parts of the application need to interact with the database, then they *borrow* a connection from the pool, use it to make a query, and release the connection back to the pool. This makes efficient use of the connections and removes the overhead of setting up and tearing down connections as well as reduces the thrashing that results from creating and releasing the connection object resources.

Now, switching over to DynamoDB: [things look a bit different](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Accessing.html). You no longer have persistent connections from the client to a database server. When you execute a Dynamo operation (query, scan, etc.) it's an HTTP request/response which means the connection is established ad-hoc and lasts only the duration of the requests. DynamoDB is a web service and it takes care of load balancing and routing to get you consistent performance regardless of scale. In this case it is generally better for applications to use a single DynamoDB client object per instance and let the client and the associated service-side infrastructure take care of the load balancing and routing.

Now, the DynamoDB client for your stack (ie. Java client, .NET client, JavaScript/NodeJS client etc.) will typically make use of an underlying HTTP client  that is pooled, mostly to minimize the costs associated with creating and tearing down these objects. And you can tweak some of those settings, and in some cases provide your own HTTP client pool implementation, but usually that is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I just now found the reply. For some reason, the app didn't show notification. When you say persistent client, you mean the workbench applications? So, making HTTP requests from my application server to Amazon RDS is same as Dynamo Db calls right?

Comment: A “persistent connection” means that the connection is made and kept open, then reused by several commands. However, with DynamoDb that is not the case. When you make a request a connection is established and then released once the request is completed.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to confirm if I call Amazon RDS service, would it be a persistent connection or not

Comment: It depends. RDS is a managed relational database offering. You *can* have a persistent connection but it is not always the case